# ANTLR4 Parser Rule granularity

Tags: antlr4

Say I have a grammar that has a parser rule to match one of several specific strings. 
Is the proper thing to do in the grammar to make an alternate parser rule for each specific string, or to keep the parser rule general and decode the string in a visitor subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the specific strings are meaningful (e.g. a keyword in a DSL) it sounds like you want Tokens.  Whatever rules you have in the grammar can reference the Tokens you created.

Generally, it's better to have your grammar do as much of the parser work as possible, rather than overly generalizing and having to write a bunch of extra code.

See the following: http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Grammar+Structure

Comment: Great! That was my instinct is to use Tokens instead rather than needlessly complicate things. Thanks for the help!